# "Divide by zero encountered in log" when not dividing by zero

Tags: python, numpy

When I do:

```
summing += yval * np.log(sigmoid(np.dot(w.transpose(), xi.transpose()))) + (1-yval)* np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(w.transpose(), xi.transpose())))
```

where there is no division, why do I get a "divide by zero encountered in log" error? As a result, `summing` becomes `[nan]`.

Comment: You should probably break that statement up into more than one line. It's extremely difficult to understand what's going on and will make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's the warning you get when you try to evaluate log with 0:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.log(0)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

I agree it's not very clear.

So in your case, I would check why your input to log is 0.

PS: this is on numpy 1.10.4

Comment: What version? I get -inf.

Comment: @Reti43: It's just a warning, not an exception.  It returns `-inf`, but it still displays the warning.

Comment: This is on numpy 1.10.4.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm on 1.10.0 and it doesn't give any warning.

Comment: @Reti43: It might just be that you already got the warning once and Python isn't issuing it again in the same session. It might show up again in a fresh interpreter. (I don't have a numpy 1.10.0 install to check.)

Comment: Thank you! But could the output of the sigmoid function possibly be zero? sigmoid is 1/(1+ math.exp(-gamma))

Comment: It does not have to. If it's 1, then you will feed 0 to log.

Comment: Oh, the second part... I see.

Comment: Glad it helped. The warning is not good, it should be improved.

Answer (score 19):

I had this same problem. It looks like you're trying to do logistic regression. I was doing MULTI-CLASS Classification with logistic regression. But you need to solve this problem using the ONE VS ALL approach (google for details).

If you don't set your yval variable so that only has '1' and '0' instead of yval = [1,2,3,4,...] etc., then you will get negative costs which lead to runaway theta and then lead to you reaching the limit of log(y) where y is close to zero.

The fix should be to pre-treat your yval variable so that it only has '1' and '0' for positive and negative examples.

Answer (score 11):

Even though it's late, this answer might help someone else.

In the part of your code.

```
... + (1-yval)* np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(w.transpose(), xi.transpose())))
```

may be the `np.dot(w.transpose(), xi.transpose())` function is spitting larger values(above 40 or so), resulting in the output of `sigmoid( )` to be `1`. And then you're basically taking `np.log` of `1-1` that is `0`. And as [DevShark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229376/10732894) has mentioned above, it causes the `RuntimeWarning: Divide by zero...` error.

How I came up with the number 40 you might ask, well, it's just that for values above 40 or so sigmoid function in python(numpy) returns `1.`.

Looking at your implementation, it seems you're dealing with the Logistic Regression algorithm, in which case(I'm under the impression that) **feature scaling is very important**.

Since I'm writing answer for the first time, It is possible I may have violated some rules/regulations, if that is the case I'd like to apologise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a very small value, e.g., 1e-7, to the input. For example, sklearn library has a parameter `eps` for the log_loss function.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge/discussion/48701