# Newton method in python / scipy

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, newtons-method

i am trying to get root of a function using Newton's algorithm on python. I have a runtime error even if i change the precision level. can you kindly help me understand how can i improve it?

Best,
GB

Below my 'simple' code and the root finding part:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import scipy.optimize as opt


def vega_callspread(r,S,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2):

    d1 = (np.log(S/K1)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (np.log(S/K2)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))

    u1 = S*np.exp(-q*T)*norm.pdf(d1,0,1)
    u2 = S*np.exp(-q*T)*norm.pdf(d2,0,1)

    return u1-u2;

x0=112
r=0
T=1
d=0
sigma=0.2
q=0
K1=110
K2=130




res2= opt.newton(vega_callspread, x0, args=(r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2,),tol=10**(-1),maxiter=1000000)


the error i get is: res2= opt.zeros.newton(vega_callspread, x0, args=(r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2,),tol=10**(-1),maxiter=1000000)
/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py:173: RuntimeWarning: Tolerance of 0.011300000000005639 reached
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give advice with such sparse context. But some remarks:

### A:

You are not using newton, as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html#scipy.optimize.newton):

> The Newton-Raphson method is used if the derivative fprime of func is provided, otherwise the secant method is used.

### B:

Your error comes from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/optimize/zeros.py#L149) i would say:

As those tol-values are hardcoded, i suppose this should not happen!

```
# Secant method
p0 = x0
if x0 >= 0:
    p1 = x0*(1 + 1e-4) + 1e-4
else:
    p1 = x0*(1 + 1e-4) - 1e-4
q0 = func(*((p0,) + args))
q1 = func(*((p1,) + args))
for iter in range(maxiter):
    if q1 == q0:
        if p1 != p0:
            msg = "Tolerance of %s reached" % (p1 - p0)
            warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
        return (p1 + p0)/2.0
```

Meaning: there is probably something wrong with your code!

### C:

Let's try the slower but more safe [bisection-method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html#scipy.optimize.bisect):

```
# brackets not tuned! it's just some trial!
res2 = opt.bisect(vega_callspread, 0, 200, args=(r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2))
```

Output:

```
X:\so_newton.py:9: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  d1 = (np.log(S/K1)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
X:\so_newton.py:10: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  d2 = (np.log(S/K2)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
```

That's a bad sign.

### D (follows C):

Your func reads:

```
def vega_callspread(r,S,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2):

    d1 = (np.log(S/K1)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (np.log(S/K2)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))

    u1 = S*np.exp(-q*T)*norm.pdf(d1,0,1)
    u2 = S*np.exp(-q*T)*norm.pdf(d2,0,1)

    return u1-u2;
```

and you call with:

```
x0=112
r=0
T=1
d=0
sigma=0.2
q=0
K1=110
K2=130

args=(r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2,)
```

**There is no S!**

So either you are dangerously renaming variables or there is some error on your end!

The value of `S` is the problem in `log(S/K1)` and co.

It's not about `S/K1` but about this:

```
import numpy as np
np.log(0)
# __main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
# -inf
```

which i got from [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229340/divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log-when-not-dividing-by-zero/36229376).

You can try to interpret what this is doing to your function now as this log-eval will get the value of `-np.inf`.

### E How is scipy handling this (follows D):

I'm too lazy to read the docs/sources of args-handling, but let's check something (add a print to the func; use bisection as earlier):

```
def vega_callspread(r,S,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2):

    print('S: ', S)

    d1 = (np.log(S/K1)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (np.log(S/K2)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))

    u1 = S*np.exp(-q*T)*norm.pdf(d1,0,1)
    u2 = S*np.exp(-q*T)*norm.pdf(d2,0,1)

    return u1-u2;
```

Output:

```
S:  0
X:\so_newton.py:11: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  d1 = (np.log(S/K1)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
X:\so_newton.py:12: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  d2 = (np.log(S/K2)+(r+sigma*sigma/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))
S:  0
```

So it seems arg-handling is by arg-name (and not just param-position in the call; i'm missing the correct programming-language terms here; again lazy!)

**This (S=0) is probably very bad (and not what you want) and this is an error on your end!**

**EDIT**

After your comment, it seems you try to optimize `S`. That made it clear to me, that you are using some optimization-algorithm optimizing `x` where you don't have `x` in your function!

I'm not analyzing your task here, but you probably want to make your function to use some `x` (initialized by `x0`) as this is the general idea of `scipy.optimize`. We can keep the name `S`, but it needs to be the first parameter of the function. This is all explained in the docs.

So:

```
def vega_callspread(S, r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2):  # S now first argument !!!
    ...

res2= opt.newton(vega_callspread, x0, args=(r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2,),tol=10**(-1),maxiter=1000000)  # S removed from args; S is init by x0 -> read docs!
```

Output:

```
117.214682594
```

Comment: many thanks for your comments it is helpful! actually in my optimization i want to solve for S when my function = 0. so perhaps the args=(r,T,d,sigma,q,K1,K2,) part is not correct. have you an idea how i can twitch it?

Comment: It's not a comment. It's an answer in SOs terms. Answers are usually upvoted if helping (and one should not always assume one transforms your non-working solution to a working one; but just pointing to obvious problems) ;-). **edit** Read my answer-edit!

Comment: this works perfectly i should have tried to invert the order indeed. many thanks for your help!

Comment: @phacoo Maybe it's time to accept the answer then. I suppose new users should be able to do that, right?

Comment: Hi sacha, i would be glad to accept it. i validated it already. kindly let me know if something else to do on my side.